# Every infinite ordinal is equinumerous with an aleph

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently reading the textbook 'Einführung in die Mengenlehre' by Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus, which does not seem to have been translated into English. While reading, I got stuck in a proof of the claim that every infinite ordinal is equinumerous with an aleph. Here are the details.

The claim is

- For every $\omega \leq \alpha$ there is at least one $\beta$ such that there is a bijection from $\alpha$ onto $\aleph_\beta$.

The proof Ebbinghaus gives goes as follows:

Since $\alpha < \aleph_{\alpha + 1}$ the set $\{ \gamma : \aleph_\gamma \leq \alpha \}$ exists. Thus, for $\beta := \bigcup\{\gamma: \aleph_\gamma \leq \alpha\}$ we have that $\aleph_\beta = \bigcup \{ \aleph_\gamma: \aleph_\gamma \leq \alpha\} \leq \alpha < \aleph_{\beta+1}$. So, by the definition of the aleph-operation, there is a bijection from $\alpha$ onto $\aleph_\beta.\space  \space \Box$

The only thing about this proof I do not understand is why $\alpha < \aleph_{\beta + 1}$ holds. The result immediately follows if $\aleph_\beta = \alpha$. But I am not sure how to tackle the case that $\aleph_\beta < \alpha$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\aleph_{\beta + 1} \leq \alpha$. Then we would have $\beta + 1 \in \{\gamma \mid \aleph_\gamma \leq \alpha\}$. Then $\beta + 1 \leq \beta$. Contradiction. Thus, $\alpha < \alpha_{\beta + 1}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

The negation of $\alpha<\aleph_{\beta+1}$ is $\aleph_{\beta+1}\le \alpha,$ but by assumption $\beta+1$ is not in the set $\{\gamma:\aleph_\gamma\le \alpha\}.$ In other words, $\beta$ is by definition at least as large as any $\gamma$ such that $\aleph_\gamma \le \alpha;$ but $\beta<\beta+1.$